# How to De/serialize an object of generic type not using BinaryFormatter?

Tags: c#, asp.net

so this is the situation: i have an object which i know the type and i want to send it from socket to socket using TCP/IP. So in order to send information i have to transform the object to a byte[] and when i receive the byte[] transform it to an object.

Isaw several solutions using MemoryStream and BinaryFormatter, but i'm not allowed to use BinaryFormatter in my application. So i have to made a custom BinaryFormatter.

Can somebody help me or guide me what should i do or what should i use?

Comment: I would use Marshal methods.  Then you can use StrToPtr and PtrToStr.   Use can then work with byte arrays.  When sending the bytes array over TCP put a byte count before the array of bytes.

Comment: Please elaborate on the limitations that force you not using Binary formatter? Can you use any other serializer?

Comment: Why can't you use binaryformatter? That's an odd restriction

Comment: It’s an application for a subject in my university, and in the letter of the problem says that we can’t use BinaryFormatter. I don’t know the reasons why we can’t use it only I know it’s i can’t use it, LOL xD. I think we can use another serializer but I need the parser from object to byte[] and from byte[] to object

Comment: I guess the reason maybe is to test your problem solving skills and/or to get you to implement your own version of that functionality so that you gain a more in depth understanding of binary file processing